# Not able to convert String to Date in VB.Net 2005. Tried Convert.ToDateTime, ParseExact. I couldn't found similar issue anywhere. Hlep needed

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb 2005 and grid view where I need to do some cell changes on basis of days difference where two dates are taken from two cells and day difference is calculated. But converting string to date is giving me weird errors.

Code part 1: Here we are taking string from two cells:

```
Protected Sub rowDataBoundForColor(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gd1.RowDataBound
    'Dim ddl As TextBox = TryCast(, TextBox)
    'msgShow2(ddl.SelectedValue)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso e.Row.RowIndex <> gd1.EditIndex Then
        Dim ddl As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Label25"), Label)
        If ddl.Text.Trim.Length > 7 Then

            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGreen
            'e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False
            e.Row.Cells(0).Enabled = False
            Dim notify As Button = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("NotifyButton"), Button)
            notify.Visible = "True"


            '============ This is the concern code
            Dim IndDt As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Label14"), Label)
            Dim payDt As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Label25"), Label)

            Dim IndDtS As String = IndDt.Text.Trim
            Dim payDtS As String = payDt.Text.Trim

            Dim t1 As String = IndDt.Text.Trim
            Dim t2 As String = payDt.Text.Trim


            If InStr(IndDtS, "/") > 0 Then
                IndDtS = IndDtS.ToString.Replace("/", "-")
            End If

            If InStr(IndDtS, ".") > 0 Then
                IndDtS = IndDtS.ToString.Replace(".", "-")
            End If

            If InStr(payDtS, "/") > 0 Then
                payDtS = payDtS.ToString.Replace("/", "-")
            End If

            If InStr(payDtS, ".") > 0 Then
                payDtS = payDtS.ToString.Replace(".", "-")
            End If

            ' function to convert string to date called here
            If (IndDtS.Length > 7 And IndDtS.Length < 11) Then
                dateRefiner(IndDtS)

            End If
            
            ' function to convert string to date called here
            If (payDtS.Length > 7 And payDtS.Length < 11) Then
                dateRefiner(payDtS)
            ElseIf payDtS.Length > 10 Then
                Dim st() As String = payDtS.Split(" ")
                dateRefiner(st(st.Length - 1).Trim)
            End If


            Dim IndDate As DateTime = IndDtS
            Dim payDate As DateTime = payDtS

            Dim ID As Label = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Label25"), Label)
            If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, payDate, IndDate) > 30 Then
                'ID.Style.Add("color", "Red")
            End If

            If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, payDate, IndDate) > 45 Then
                'e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red

            End If
            '============
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Part 2: the function definition:

```
Protected Sub dateRefiner(ByRef DateS)
    Dim fSt2() As String
    Dim oDate As DateTime

    fSt2 = DateS.ToString.Trim.Split("-")

    'dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy converted below
    Dim dateR As String = fSt2(1) + "/" + fSt2(0) + "/" + fSt2(2)
    Try
        oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateR, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgShow2("Refined Date:" + dateR + "Converted Date : " + oDate)
    End Try

    DateS = oDate

End Sub
```

Error:
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

At:
oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateR, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

On Using a pop up through msgShow2() function, I tried getting the what is the converted date and original data. And I found something weird. Screenshot attached for this[See original string and converted string in the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dZfa.jpg)

Comment: I think you have some issues whenever exists a date in a single digit (without zeros) 
Try doing this: `Dim dateR As String = fSt2(1).ToString("00") + "/" + fSt2(0).ToString("00")  +…...`

Comment: However you can use also `oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateS.ToString, "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` avoiding splitting and detecting date’s data

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After doing ur suggested changes, I got error:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.

Comment: G3nt_M3caj , tried second suggestion, got error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Convert data in integer as follows:  `CInt(fSt2(1)).ToString("00") + "/" + CInt(fSt2(0)).ToString("00") +....`

Comment: Hey, it worked. Thanks a lot. Could you tell me why it worked?

Comment: The method `.ToString` accept different parameters for different types which are not the same in all cases. Saying that, you have to normalize your data’s data in string format before you’ll going to convert them in Date type. You have to consider also wrongest situation than yours. Stay safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format. Or change the data

format = dd/MM/yyyy  -> 07/04/2021

format  = d/M/yyyy  -> 7/4/2021

```
Dim dateR As String = fSt2(1).PadLeft(2, "0") + "/" + fSt2(0).PadLeft(2, "0") + "/" + fSt2(2)
```

I tested like below and it worked
If there is an error, try adding a leading zero to the data :)

```
     Dim oDate As DateTime
      Dim dateR As String = "7/4/2021"

      Try

         oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateR,"d/M/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
         MsgBox(oDate)
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox("Refined Date:" + dateR + "Converted Date : " + oDate)
         MsgBox(ex.ToString)
      End Try
```

Comment: I handled the formatting as you said and tried still the same error.  Converted date is as shown in attached pic.

Comment: I answered again.

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I followed the comment by G3nt_M3caj.